# setInterval() con tiempos variables

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de sincronizar una animacion con la musica de fondo. Para esto estoy usando la funcion **setInterval()** de javascript.

Cual es el problema con el que me tope es que dicha funcion tiene un paramtro (tiempo) fijo.

Yo necesito ejecutar la animacion a los 10 segundos, despues a los 18 seg, despues a los 40 seg, etc...

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cadaTiempo = 10000;

        setInterval(function () {
            try {
                $('#divCampo').ripples({
                    interactive: false,
                    resolution: 128,
                    perturbance: 0.1,
                });
            }
            catch (e) {
                $('.error').show().text(e);
            }

            var tiempoDestruct = 1800;

            tirarOla(tiempoDestruct);

        }, cadaTiempo);

    });

    function sleep(time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

    function tirarOla(tiempo) {
        var $el = $('#divCampo');
        var x = $el.width()/2;
        var y = $el.height()/2;
        var dropRadius = 30;
        var strength = 0.05;

        $el.ripples('updateSize');

        $el.ripples('drop', x, y, dropRadius, strength);

        sleep(tiempo).then(() => {
            $el.ripples('destroy');
        });
    }
</script>
```

PD: Trade de usar IF anidado para cambiar el valor de la variable **cadaTiempo**, controlandola con flags, pero no me salio. La animacion sigue ejecuntandose cada 10 seg de todas formas.

```
if(flag == 1){
  cadaTiempo == 10000;
  flag++;
}else if(flag == 2){
  cadaTiempo == 18000; 
  flag++;
}
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas es esperar una cierta cantidad de segundos para que se ejecute la animación ? Siendo así debes usar setTimeout() o necesitas que se ejecute cada 10 segundos y después cada 18 .... no entiendo bien

Comment: Te doy un ejemplo: Suponete que la cancion dura 3 minutos. Necesito ejecutar una animacion a lo largo de ese tiempo, pero no cada tiempo fijo, si no que ese tiempo tiene que variar.

Comment: Es que lo que hace setInterval() es ejecutar una función cada cierto tiempo y lo que hace setTimeout() es esperar cierto tiempo para ejecutar una función, cuando dices "Yo necesito ejecutar la animación a los 10 segundos, después a los 18 seg, después a los 40 seg..." me hace mas referencia a que necesitas esperar esa cantidad de segundos para ejecutar, es por eso que te doy la opción de usar setTimeout()

Comment: Segun lei esa funcion que decis vos, se ejecuta 1 sola vez.

Comment: Si lo haces de una manera recursiva se ejecuta como lo necesitas, te copiaré la respuesta y me dices si te sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que una posible solución podría ser utilizar en una función recursiva el `setTimeout()`, te coloco un ejemplo de función recursiva para que lo agregues a tu lógica:

```js
var tiempo = 0;

function ejecutar(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        ejecutar();
    }, tiempo)

    tiempo += 1000;
    
    $("#mensaje").append('<p>Me ejecuté a los ' + tiempo + ' milisegundos</p>');
}

ejecutar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo. No sabia que era recursiva esa funcion.

Comment: Claro, al llamar la misma función dentro del setTimeout() se vuelve una función recursiva, me alegra que te haya servido !